# Having trouble Jest testing ajax modules with axios

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, redux, jestjs, axios

I have a module called `ajax.js` that exports a bunch of ajax functions for me. I'm trying to test the following function with Jest:

```js
export const status = ({loginUrl='/', logoutUrl='/'}) => {
  return axios.get(`/auth?login=${loginUrl}&logout=${logoutUrl}`);
};
```

My test looks like this:

```js
jest.unmock('../ajax');

import { status } from '../ajax';

describe('ajax', () => {
  let urls;

  beforeEach(() => {
    urls = {
      loginUrl: '/',
      logoutUrl: '/'
    };
  });

  it('calls status with a login and logout url', () => {
    const { loginUrl, logoutUrl } = urls;

    status(urls);
    expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith(`/auth?login=${loginUrl}&logout=${logoutUrl}`);
  });
});
```

I keep getting a runtime error in my test:

[image: runtime jest error]

If I `unmock` axios, the error goes away, but that doesn't help me because I want axios to be mocked!

Also, the error appears to be happening because of this line:

```js
import { status } from '../ajax';
```

Why is Jest struggling with axios so much. Why is simply importing my `status` function causing this error? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hi, have you find a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution based on:

```
"jest": "^24.8.0",
"ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
"tslint": "^5.18.0",
"typescript": "^3.5.3"
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
```

`ajax.ts`:

```js
import { status } from './ajax';
import axios from 'axios';

const originalGet = axios.get;
axios.get = jest.fn();

describe('ajax', () => {
  let urls;

  beforeEach(() => {
    urls = {
      loginUrl: '/',
      logoutUrl: '/'
    };
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    axios.get = originalGet;
  });

  it('calls status with a login and logout url', async () => {
    const { loginUrl, logoutUrl } = urls;
    (axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>).get.mockResolvedValueOnce('mocked data');
    const actualValue = await status(urls);
    expect(actualValue).toBe('mocked data');
    expect(axios.get).toBeCalledWith(`/auth?login=${loginUrl}&logout=${logoutUrl}`);
  });

  it('should restore original get', () => {
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(axios.get)).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/38129774/ajax.spec.ts
  ajax
    ✓ calls status with a login and logout url (7ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.906s, estimated 3s
```